# GooglePlayServices Admob issue : "Failed to load ad : 0"

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I have a problem with the new admob.

Here is my code, trying to create and load an ad in my main activity :

```
private void createAndLoadAd(String adUnitID, RelativeLayout rlRoot, View upperView){
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId(adUnitID);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setId(R.id.ad_view);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(AdView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, AdView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

    rlRoot.addView(adView, params);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams upperViewParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) upperView.getLayoutParams();
    upperViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.ad_view);
    upperView.setLayoutParams(upperViewParams);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    checkGooglePlayServices(this);
}
```

I have a RelativeLayout in my XML, and I'm trying to place the ad just below an ExpandableListView (only child).

Here is what I get :

> W/Ads﹕ There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0 W/Ads﹕
>
> Failed to load ad: 0

I precise that I have all the permission needed in my AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

And here is the gradle line :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+'
```

I read that the error may come from the adUnitID, I tried to recreate a new one but didn't work.

Maybe there is some new rules that if the application is not released in the market, ads won't work ?

Here is the log concerning the problem :

```
01-31 09:48:37.687  19580-19580/me.frozened.rappel I/Ads﹕ Starting ad request.
01-31 09:48:37.872  19580-19580/me.frozened.rappel E/﹕ file /data/data/com.nvidia.NvCPLSvc/files/driverlist.txt: not found!
01-31 09:48:37.872  19580-19580/me.frozened.rappel I/﹕ Attempting to load EGL implementation /system/lib//egl/libEGL_tegra_impl
01-31 09:48:37.887  19580-19580/me.frozened.rappel I/﹕ Loaded EGL implementation /system/lib//egl/libEGL_tegra_impl
01-31 09:48:37.912  19580-19580/me.frozened.rappel I/﹕ Loading GLESv2 implementation /system/lib//egl/libGLESv2_tegra_impl
01-31 09:48:40.767  19580-19580/me.frozened.rappel W/KeyCharacterMap﹕ Load KCM of non-default device may incur unexpected result
01-31 09:48:48.217  19580-19617/me.frozened.rappel W/Ads﹕ There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
01-31 09:48:48.222  19580-19580/me.frozened.rappel W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3114: Landroid/webkit/WebView;.evaluateJavascript (Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/webkit/ValueCallback;)V
01-31 09:48:48.302  19580-19833/me.frozened.rappel W/﹕ init htc webcore
01-31 09:48:48.337  19580-19580/me.frozened.rappel W/Ads﹕ Failed to load ad: 0
```

Edit :

The problem seems to be not isolated. I did a lot of tests, and from my ten tests, only two worked. I don't understand, maybe the new admob is not working very well ?

I tested these applications on the following devices :

- HTC One X <- Not working (the logs are for this one)
- Nexus 5 <- Working
- Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 <- Not working
- Sasmung Galaxy Ace <- Not working
- Samsung Galaxy Note 3 <- Not working
- Sony Xperia Z <- Working
- Samsung Galaxy Alpha <- Not Working
- Samsung Galaxy S3 <- Not working

Some of theses phones are using the latest version of Google Play Services (my HTC One X, my Nexus 5, the Galaxy Note 3). I don't know for the other ones.

Here are the two apps I tested : 
 - [Rappel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.frozened.rappel) <- The first problematic app
 - [My Word Book](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.frozenarts.mynotebook) <- An old app whom I'm sure the ads worked before
 - [BMI](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sabalotelli.imc) <- A friend app in the same situation

So I have two hypothesis : either I tested these applications on phones who are not working very well (I would belive it...), or there is some permission/code I forgot to add.

Plus, my HTC One X doesn't have a SIM card (I only use Internet). May this be the problem for this phone ?

Comment: What adUnitId are you providing? And post the full logcat

Comment: I did not find any solution for this phone yet. So I tried my application with a newer phone, and it worked without adding anything. I'm using the new phone in order to debug my phone, but it would be cool to know if this problem is specific to my phone, or to a bigger scale.

Comment: So post the logcat from the phone on which it is failing

Comment: @William I'll do it tonight

Comment: I edited the answer and put the 4 log lines concerning the problem. Should I put all the log ?

Comment: Yes, put all the log. And change the play-service dependency in your Gradle file to be eplxicit abut what version to use. eg compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'

Comment: @William Forgot to post a message that I put all the log and tried your solution but didn't worked. The problem is now on other phones too.

Comment: You still have shown exactly which version of PlayServices you are using. Nor listed the devices on which it is occurring. The log seems to indicate a failing with Nvidia drivers.

Comment: @William Here is the edit. I put all my tests, and the versions of Google Play Services.

Comment: `WebView.evlauteJavascript()' is only available from Android 19 onwards. What have you configured you min and targetSDK in your AndroidManifest?

Comment: What is WebView.evlauteJavascript() ? My targetSDK is 20.

Comment: Your log says "W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3114: Landroid/webkit/WebView;.evaluateJavascript (Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/webkit/ValueCallback;)V"

Comment: What is your minSDK and what version of Android is running on the devices?

Comment: Min SDK is 16. My Nexus has Version L (5.0.1) and my HTC is 17 (4.2.2). Is that the problem ?

Comment: I think targetSDK=20 may be confusing either Admob or the WebView on your HTC into trying to use API that doesn't exist on that device. Try setting targetSDK back to 17 and test again on your HTC

Comment: @William Didn't work. The same problem occurred. The evaluateJavascript method was a dalvikvm error, do you think there is a relation with ads ?

Comment: It's happening on the same thread (19580-19580) as the ad load, so I think it's a product of the load. It's only a warning, but I wouldn't have expected that method to have been called on a device that doesn't support it.

Comment: @William Yes it's my opinion too. I will try to debug this app with another smartphone in Android version 17.

Comment: @FR073N Have you solved this problem then please answer your question ! I am facing the same problem, how did you solved it?

Comment: @vivek-warde I did not solved this problem. I developed on a phone where this problem was not present... Today, I don't know if the problem is still present or not.

Comment: Hi, @FR073N Pleasse see my answer below, It is fixed in my case

Answer (score 2):

Actually, my code was right & I was having an updated google play services library in my android. My admob account was new with new banner & interstial id's

It automatically got fixed & start getting the ad response after waiting 1-2 days. Since then everything works well.

Comment: I'll try it on my phone. My account is two years old, but maybe there was an update that corrected this problem.

Comment: Voted up... Let's wait for some time now

Comment: Being Patient Worked again :)  Before it was giving error (0 and 3). But started working after few minutes. [p.s I followed the new Firebase Ads guide]

Answer (score 1):

In My case i forget to use

`.addTestDevice("1C51F744DXXXXXXXX64F06586C84EF")`

You will get your device id in the log.

Comment: That's it! It was the issue in my case!

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you're on a **custom ROM** like **CyanogenMod**, which doesn't come with Google apps (**G-Apps**) like Play Store, Gmail, by default.

So you'll have to:

1. Download the appropriate GApps package for your OS from [this wiki](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps#Downloads).
2. Flash it. *([Instructions to flash if you don't know how](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps#Installation))*
3. Open the Play Store app. It'll ask you to log-in with your Google Account.
4. Then update the Google Play Services app

If you've done the coding properly, ads should now be displayed.