# Admob adBanner not shown in android application, Failed to Load AD

Tags: android, admob

Banner ads from AdMob has been added in the application both in XML and code but while running the application in the external device ,the banner Ad is not shown and the below error is shown in `logcat`.

NB: Googled this issue many times but not found any appropriate solution for this problem.
Updated the google play service but that not solved the issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/username_textinput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext_agentid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:ems="5"
                android:hint="User name"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColorHint="#000000"/>


        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>



        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/edittext_textinput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:ems="5"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textColorHint="#000000" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        <Button
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/button_login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="LOGIN"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            android:paddingRight="40dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the adrequest code in the activity

```
adview=(AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adview.loadAd(adRequest);
```

While running the application this is the error in `logcat`.
`/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response.  ErrorCode: 0 W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0`

[image]

Comment: There are lots of similar questions, just google this: "Failed to load ad: 0"

Comment: googled and found many results  but none of them give me the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GooglePlayServices Admob issue : "Failed to load ad : 0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766271/googleplayservices-admob-issue-failed-to-load-ad-0)

Comment: But that doesn't have a solution for my problem.

Comment: Try to clear-data of the Play-Services app.

Answer (score 1):

Test ads as tester

```
adview=(AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new 
AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("your id").build();
adview.loadAd(adRequest);
```

After run the app... Go in Logcat put in Verbose put in the search field AdRequest, so the id device shows donw.

Comment: Is it necessary to give device ID while running in external android device.

Comment: put any testDevice id from other than you got correct device in log cat.

Comment: test device id means  emulator  ID or my external device ID.

Comment: Add this id 33BE2250B43518CCDA7DE426D04EE232 i knew this is not your id but correct one show in logcat for emulator or external device what evere use i hope this help.